# aov_car, [.data.frame`(data, , id) : undefined columns selected

Tags: r, undefined, anova

I have a dataset:

```
# A tibble: 6 x 4
     id condition type       accuracy
  <dbl> <fct>     <fct>         <dbl>
1     1 alg       suggestion        4
2     1 alg       benefit           3
3     1 alg       order             3
4     2 alg       suggestion        2
5     2 alg       benefit           4
6     2 alg       order             1
```

I want to create a anova-model:

```
model<- aov_car(accuracy ~ condition*type +
                  Error(Subject), data=alg_long, observed = "type")
```

But I get the error-message:

```
`[.data.frame`(data, , id) : undefined columns selected
```

How can I solve that??

Comment: You're calling for a column `Subject` but there is not one in your current example

Comment: @TheSciGuy: Thank you!!